# How to access a nested object in JSON via Python

Tags: python, json

I have a single entry in a JSON file. Within the `"objects":[]` list, I have `"title":`. I want to create a list that appends the value of every `"title":` in every JSON list. In the end, my goal is to have a list like this:

`titles = [Mastercard, Mastercard, Alienware, Oppo, Alienware, ...]`

```
{
  "ID": "ckksku7b800003e5m5vne0v7c",
  "DataRow ID": "ckkskgs561yh00sgog3vf1v29",
  "Labeled Data": "https://storage.labelbox.com/ckkqt5y5ulks20757tbduodbw%2Fe2510252-76ba-df14-193b-43d4527d705a-Screenshot%202021-02-05%20at%2017.46.56.png?Expires=1614084797277&KeyName=labelbox-assets-key-1&Signature=e69tqkxYhNNWkJL3TaxA9wjtYGM",
  "Label": {
    "objects": [
      {
        "featureId": "ckkskpirs0koo0y771e2veiik",
        "schemaId": "ckkskil310j1o0y8r0fu252jy",
        "title": "Mastercard",
        "value": "mastercard",
        "color": "#006FA6",
        "bbox": {
          "top": 631,
          "left": 891,
          "height": 25,
          "width": 40
        },
        "instanceURI": "https://api.labelbox.com/masks/feature/ckkskpirs0koo0y771e2veiik?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiJja2txdDV5NmFtbm1iMDc0MGpsem03d2RwIiwib3JnYW5pemF0aW9uSWQiOiJja2txdDV5NXVsa3MyMDc1N3RiZHVvZGJ3IiwiaWF0IjoxNjEyODc1MTk3LCJleHAiOjE2MTU0NjcxOTd9.P-MyOgZidmSZSTLfhwpSsRfOaovsReP5MzpDtsrnWs0"
      },
      {
        "featureId": "ckkskqn410l530y770svj1z3g",
        "schemaId": "ckkskil310j1o0y8r0fu252jy",
        "title": "Mastercard",
        "value": "mastercard",
        "color": "#006FA6",
        "bbox": {
          "top": 374,
          "left": 1248,
          "height": 22,
          "width": 33
        },
        "instanceURI": "https://api.labelbox.com/masks/feature/ckkskqn410l530y770svj1z3g?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiJja2txdDV5NmFtbm1iMDc0MGpsem03d2RwIiwib3JnYW5pemF0aW9uSWQiOiJja2txdDV5NXVsa3MyMDc1N3RiZHVvZGJ3IiwiaWF0IjoxNjEyODc1MTk3LCJleHAiOjE2MTU0NjcxOTd9.P-MyOgZidmSZSTLfhwpSsRfOaovsReP5MzpDtsrnWs0"
      },
      {
        "featureId": "ckkskshox0luo0y77gozzbuzu",
        "schemaId": "ckksks2sh0lrl0y8rcq970g3u",
        "title": "Alienware",
        "value": "alienware",
        "color": "#A30059",
        "bbox": {
          "top": 436,
          "left": 1901,
          "height": 31,
          "width": 86
        },
        "instanceURI": "https://api.labelbox.com/masks/feature/ckkskshox0luo0y77gozzbuzu?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiJja2txdDV5NmFtbm1iMDc0MGpsem03d2RwIiwib3JnYW5pemF0aW9uSWQiOiJja2txdDV5NXVsa3MyMDc1N3RiZHVvZGJ3IiwiaWF0IjoxNjEyODc1MTk3LCJleHAiOjE2MTU0NjcxOTd9.P-MyOgZidmSZSTLfhwpSsRfOaovsReP5MzpDtsrnWs0"
      },
      {
        "featureId": "ckksktu8c0mhq0y8r6a82cjgm",
        "schemaId": "ckkskil300j1g0y8r5kbgguk9",
        "title": "OPPO",
        "value": "oppo",
        "color": "#1CE6FF",
        "bbox": {
          "top": 1101,
          "left": 1837,
          "height": 19,
          "width": 51
        },
        "instanceURI": "https://api.labelbox.com/masks/feature/ckksktu8c0mhq0y8r6a82cjgm?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiJja2txdDV5NmFtbm1iMDc0MGpsem03d2RwIiwib3JnYW5pemF0aW9uSWQiOiJja2txdDV5NXVsa3MyMDc1N3RiZHVvZGJ3IiwiaWF0IjoxNjEyODc1MTk3LCJleHAiOjE2MTU0NjcxOTd9.P-MyOgZidmSZSTLfhwpSsRfOaovsReP5MzpDtsrnWs0"
      },
      {
        "featureId": "ckkxvfpv305j00y8k1hvn03e8",
        "schemaId": "ckksks2sh0lrl0y8rcq970g3u",
        "title": "Alienware",
        "value": "alienware",
        "color": "#A30059",
        "bbox": {
          "top": 505,
          "left": 2276,
          "height": 23,
          "width": 92
        },
        "instanceURI": "https://api.labelbox.com/masks/feature/ckkxvfpv305j00y8k1hvn03e8?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiJja2txdDV5NmFtbm1iMDc0MGpsem03d2RwIiwib3JnYW5pemF0aW9uSWQiOiJja2txdDV5NXVsa3MyMDc1N3RiZHVvZGJ3IiwiaWF0IjoxNjEyODc1MTk3LCJleHAiOjE2MTU0NjcxOTd9.P-MyOgZidmSZSTLfhwpSsRfOaovsReP5MzpDtsrnWs0"
      }
    ],
    "classifications": []
  },
  ...
}
```

**Update**
This is what I changed my code to per suggestion

```
    for i in range(0, len(data)):
        line = data[i]
        objects = line['Label']['objects']
        classes = [o['title'] for d in data for o in objects]
        print(classes)
```

This is the output:

```
['Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', ...
'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard']

['OPPO', 'OPPO', 'OPPO', 'OPPO', 'OPPO', 'OPPO', 'OPPO', 'OPPO', 'OPPO', 'OPPO', 'OPPO', 'OPPO', 'OPPO', 'OPPO', 'OPPO', 'OPPO', 'OPPO', 'OPPO', ...
'OPPO', 'OPPO', 'OPPO', 'OPPO', 'OPPO', 'OPPO', 'OPPO', 'OPPO', 'OPPO', 'OPPO', 'OPPO', 'OPPO', 'OPPO', 'OPPO', 'OPPO']

['Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard',  ...
'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard']

['Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', ...
'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard']

['Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Alienware', 'OPPO', 'Alienware', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Alienware', 'OPPO', 'Alienware', 'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Alienware', 'OPPO', 'Alienware', 
...
'Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Alienware', 'OPPO', 'Alienware']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you should be able to do this with a list comprehension:

```py
titles = [o['title'] for d in data for o in d['Label']['objects']]
```

Output (for a list containing the above object):

```
['Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Alienware', 'OPPO', 'Alienware']
```

Comment: Check the edits. I am running this for multiple JSON entries.

Comment: @oo92 sorry I didn't make it clear, you should replace your entire loop, including the `for i in range(0, len(data)):` with this one line.

Comment: @oo92 see for example https://rextester.com/JWV90069

Comment: `KeyError: 'objects'` when I replace everything with your code

Comment: @oo92 is your `data` value not the same as the one in that demo?

Comment: It is. I just think your code tries to access the title by jumping over some access points

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: Python 3.8. Its telling me that your code throws a keyerror by accessing object like that

Comment: Is `d` actually an array of objects? If not you would just use `titles = [o['title'] for o in data['Label']['objects']]` see https://rextester.com/VTEX54283

Comment: @oo92 your problem seems to be that some of the values don't have any objects; you can use a ternary condition to check for that e.g. `titles = [o['title'] for d in data for o in (d['Label']['objects'] if 'objects' in d['Label'] else [])]`

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is :

```
title = []

for j in data['Label']['objects']:
    title.append(j['title'])
```

**output:**

```
['Mastercard', 'Mastercard', 'Alienware', 'OPPO', 'Alienware']
```

if data is list of dict:

```
title = []

for d in data:
    for obj in d['Label']['objects']:
        title.append(obj['title'])
```